# MySql Full Join

Tags: mysql, database, join, outer-join, full-outer-join

I'm using MySql

So I have 5 tables and I'm trying to build a view which joins all these together and shows the missing information the current structure is.

plat (1 = Many) PG (1 = Many) TS

PG (1 = Many) PGHist

TT (1 = Many) TS

OR

[image]
I am using MySql but I am not sure how to write this as you cannot use full joins as far as i'm aware in MySql can anyone help?

I need it so show nulls to any part.

Comment: "joins all these together and shows the missing information" is not clear. Please explain what your output looks like given some input. Please give example desired output for some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using UNION of both LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN to emulate the FULL JOIN in MySQL as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM PLAT
LEFT JOIN PG ON PG.FORGEIN_KEY = PLAT.PRIMARY_KEY
LEFT JOIN PGHIST ON PGHIST.FORGEIN_KEY = PG.PRIMARY_KEY
LEFT JOIN PG ON PG.FORGEIN_KEY = PLAT.PRIMARY_KEY
LEFT JOIN TS ON TS.FORGEIN_KEY = PG.PRIMARY_KEY
LEFT JOIN TT ON TT.FORGEIN_KEY = TS.PRIMARY_KEY

UNION

SELECT * FROM PLAT
RIGHT JOIN PG ON PG.FORGEIN_KEY = PLAT.PRIMARY_KEY
RIGHT JOIN PGHIST ON PGHIST.FORGEIN_KEY = PG.PRIMARY_KEY
RIGHT JOIN PG ON PG.FORGEIN_KEY = PLAT.PRIMARY_KEY
RIGHT JOIN TS ON TS.FORGEIN_KEY = PG.PRIMARY_KEY
RIGHT JOIN TT ON TT.FORGEIN_KEY = TS.PRIMARY_KEY
```